# While loop hanging during socket conneciton in Java

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

Here is my problem, I have a program trying to communicate over a socket connection.

-I am able to connect and send "connect" to the client

-sendResponse(fromServer); receives the "connect" and performs the swtich and finishes but the while loop (while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)) will not break and nothing else happens.

The program just sits there. What am I doing wrong? I wrote this about a year ago and I don't know how I even got it to work. The last thing printed to they system is "Inside Connect"

Here is my code:

Server:

```
public static  String socketTest(String action){
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        Socket clientSocket;
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader inBuff;

        String fromClient = " ";
        int port = 6000;

        switch(action) {

            case "sync":
                out.println("sync");
                while((fromClient = inBuff.readLine()) != null) {
                log("Waiting for devices to sync");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                break;
            case "ready":
                out.println("ready");
                while((fromClient = inBuff.readLine()) != null) {
                    log("Waiting for Control PC response");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                break;
            case "connect":
                String input = "", 
                       output = "";

                try { 
                        log("**************************** Trying to listen to port 6000 ****************************");
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        inBuff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        //out.println("I am the test machine and we have connected to port 6000");              
                        out.println("connect");             
                        log("**************************** Should be listening to port 6000 now ****************************");
                    }catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //while((fromClient = inBuff.readLine()) != null) {
                    //  log("Waiting for Control PC response");
                    //  Thread.sleep(1000);
                    //}
                break;


        } // Close switch statement

        return fromClient;
    }
```

Client:

```
while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println("in while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)");

                    System.out.println("This should be the first thing from server: " + fromServer + "\n");
                    sendResponse(fromServer);

            }
```

sendResponse fucntion:

```
public static String sendResponse(String action) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        String str = " "; // Value to hold string to be returned

        switch (action) {

        case "connect":
            System.out.println("Inside connect");
            out.println("success");
            break;
        case "ready":
            System.out.println("Inside ready");
            out.println("success");
            break;
        case "sync":
            System.out.println("Inside sync");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            out.println("success");
            break;
        default:
            out.println(" ");

        }



        return str;

    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint just before the `while` loop that doesn't exit and step through it to see what is going on.

Comment: In your client code, what is the variable "in" initialized to?

Comment: The debugger will not connect to the server...